# I saw a "I Need to..." web part someplace, where to get it?

Tags: web-part

Edited: This is what I am referring to. But not sure where to get the wsp or the web part. http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/sharepoint-v3-configuring-custom-i-need.html

Some time ago, I saw a "I need to..." web part. It hooks to a list that has Url column.

A dropdown is placed on the page by this site and then you can configure to display links in a dropdown.

Properties can be configured to display a group of Urls in the drop down.

Where is this web part? I didn't see it when I wanted to drop this web part on the page? I heard it does not work well if you want the Url to be sorted.

Is there a similar webpart that I can download. I did some google search but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 3 part blog post explaining how to do a dropdown using XSL from a list - you could build your own in less than an hour.  http://paylord.wordpress.com.  The example I used does not have sort but you could easily add a number SortOrder column and sort the view the web part.

Comment: Thank you Dave. But i was looking for something like this. http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/sharepoint-v3-configuring-custom-i-need.html

Comment: Yep - that is what you would get.